# Why won't my program stop looping?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, putty

My assignment is to use two different kinds of loops (For, While, do While). The task is to ask the user to enter a number between 1 and 10 and then the program will count from 0 to the users number. Also, the program must be able to display an error message and ask the user to enter a number again if the user enters a number outside of 1 through 10. The part of the code with the error message and the prompt to enter a number again is working just fine. However, when I enter a number within the range, it either does nothing or counts from 0 to their number an infinite amount of times and won't stop looping the count. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    //Variables
    int num;
    int zero;

    //Explains to the user what the program will do
    printf("This program will count from 0 to a number you pick.\n\n");

    //Asks the user to input a value
    printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);


    //If the correct range was selected by the user
    while ( num >= 1 && num <= 10 )
    {
            for ( zero = 0; zero <= num; zero++ )
            {
                    printf("%d...", zero);

            }
    }

    //If a value outside of the accepted range is entered
    while ( num < 1 || num > 10)
    {
            printf("I'm sorry, that is incorrect.\n");
            printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
    }


    printf("\n\n\n");

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: You need to show your program.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't help you with code we can't see, based on some vague description of the problem. Please visit [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and then come back here and [edit] your question and provide an SSCCE of your **relevant** code (not a big code dump), a clear description of the problem, and ask a specific question based on that code, and perhaps we can help you figure things out.

Comment: Provide some sample code.  It doesn't need to work, but show effort.  You will need to declare a couple of variables, print a prompt, accept input, convert it to a number, and loop on that number.  take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while ( num >= 1 && num <= 10 )
    {
            for ( zero = 0; zero <= num; zero++ )
            {
                    printf("%d...", zero);

            }
    }
```

will run forever if num is between 1 and 10, since num is not changed inside the loop - once you're in, you're in for good.

If you enter a "bad" value then you'll skip this and go into your second while loop.  However once you get out of that while loop by entering a "good" value, all that's left to execute is

```
printf("\n\n\n");

return 0;
```

You need to get rid of the first while loop and move the second one above the for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    //Variables
    int num;
    int zero;

    //Explains to the user what the program will do
    printf("This program will count from 0 to a number you pick.\n\n");

    //Asks the user to input a value
    printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    //If a value outside of the accepted range is entered
    while ( num < 1 || num > 10)
    {
            printf("I'm sorry, that is incorrect.\n");
            printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
            scanf("%d", &num);
    }

   for ( zero = 0; zero <= num; zero++ )
   {
            printf("%d...", zero);

   }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change two of your while loops to if guards,

```
    num=1;
    while(num>0)
    {
    //Asks the user to input a value
    printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    //If the correct range was selected by the user
    if ( num >= 1 && num <= 10 )
    {
        for ( zero = 0; zero <= num; zero++ )
        {
            printf("%d...", zero);
        }
    }
    //If a value outside of the accepted range is entered
    if ( num < 1 || num > 10)
    {
            printf("I'm sorry, that is incorrect.\n");
            printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
            //scanf("%d", &num);
    }
        while(0); while(0); while(0); while(0); //gratuitous loops
        do ; while(0); for(;0;);
    }
```

Comment: Yes that would work but my instructor is requiring two different types of loops. So where would I put my other one if I replace the 'while' loops with 'if' statements?

Comment: Note the while(num>0) outer loop, and the for(...) inner loop. Done.

Comment: The while loops you had were breaking things.  If you want to add extraneous while loops, add this anywhere: while(0);

Answer (score 0):

**Really Simple!**

You may use a **break** inside the while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
//Variables
int num;
int zero;

//Explains to the user what the program will do
printf("This program will count from 0 to a number you pick.\n\n");

//Asks the user to input a value
printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
scanf("%d", &num);


//If the correct range was selected by the user
while ( num >= 1 && num <= 10 )
{
        for ( zero = 0; zero <= num; zero++ )
        {
                printf("%d...", zero);

        }
        break; // !!! Here !!!
}

//If a value outside of the accepted range is entered
while ( num < 1 || num > 10)
{
        printf("I'm sorry, that is incorrect.\n");
        printf("Please enter a number (between 1 and 10): \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
}


printf("\n\n\n");

return 0;


}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use an if-statement instead of while + break?